# How to write testcase for bootstrap-vue modal?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, karma-jasmine, bootstrap-vue

I want to test bootstrap vue modal displaying . In project page , modal is show/hide by toggleModal method when click button .So modal `display` style is changed to `none or ''` vice versa. In karma test , I want to test that display with method called , but its changed data only and style property is not changing so I got failed in test case ...

> vm.$nextTick(() => { 
>          expect(modal.style.display).toBe('')
>    })

*How can I acheive bootstrap-vue modal display test case correctly !?*

index.vue

```
<div id="example">
  <button @click="toggleModal">Show</button>
  <b-modal v-model="show" centered size="lg" title="確認">
  <h1>Modal Test</h1>
  <button @click="toggleModal">Hide</button>
  </b-modal>
</div>
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    show: false,
  },
  methods: {
   toggleModal: function () {
     this.show = !this.show
   }
  }
})
```

index.spec.js

```
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.esm'
import Vue from 'vue'
import Index from '~/components/index'
// Mock our router, store and nuxt-link
import Vuex from 'vuex'
// import NuxtLink from '~/.nuxt/components/nuxt-link'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.use(Vuex)

describe('/components/index.vue', () => {
  let vm

  beforeEach(() => {
    const Constructor = Vue.extend(Index)
    vm = new Constructor().$mount()
  })

  it('check modal method', () => {
     const modal = vm.$el.querySelector('.modal')
     expect(modal.style.display).toBe('none')
     modal.toggleModal()
     vm.$nextTick(() => {
       expect(modal.style.display).toBe('') //expect to pass , but fail
     })
  })
})
```

Comment: @Ferrybig Sorry that my typing error on question ! I fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Open  your browser console, then check `style.display` for the Bootstrap-Vue Modal, the value is **none** when hide(),  the value is **block !important** when show().

so change `expect(modal.style.display).toBe('')` to `expect(modal.style.display).toBe('block !important')`

or

I don't know **Karma**, probably exists one usage like `expect(modal.style.display).toBe((item)=>{return item!=='none'})`

Answer (score 0):

```
it('check modal method', () => {
 const fm = new Vue(Index).$mount()
 const modal = fm.$el.querySelector('.modal')
 expect(modal.style.display).toBe('none')
 modal.toggleModal()
 fm.$nextTick(() => {
   expect(modal.style.display).toBe('')
 })
})
```